# Allow maximum number of choices of m2m field in viewset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to allow users pick maximum 2 genres. I tried add in `models.py`, but there was an error. Now, I am thinking of adding code to check the number of picked genres in `views.py`, or may be in Serializer if it's possible.

```
class Story(models.Model):
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.genre.count() > 2:
             raise ValidationError('Error')
         super(Story, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)


class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre = GenreSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    ...

class StoryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StorySerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried and the error it gave?

Comment: @SimonCrane posted, the error is “<Story: title>” needs to have a value for field “id” before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

The problem is that you need to save objects to the database before you can create many-to-many relationships.  Try this:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.save()
         if self.genre.count() > 2:
             raise ValidationError('Error')
         super(Story, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it saves story anyway, no matter how much genres